# умножение матриц?

Tags: c++, матрицы

Подскажите как вывести умножение и результат матриц в с++
Еще проблема с матрицей 3 на 1  , как ее можно обьявить динамически чтобы потом работать с ней не как со строкой 3 4 5 например , а со столбцом
а например если у меня есть три матрицы , первая 3 на 3 , вторая 3 на 1 , третья должна быть 3 на 1 , как мне переделать функцию чтобы она считала результат для этого случая, добавил код в вопрос

```
int MultiMass(double** A, double** B, double** C, int size)//умножение
{
    cout << "A=" << endl; ShowMtx(A, size); next
        cout << "B=" << endl; ShowMtx(B, size); next
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                C[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
                {
                    C[i][j] += A[i][j] * B[j][i];
                }
            }
        }
    cout << "C="; ShowMtx(C, size);
    return 0;
}

3 5 6       7 
7 6 4   *   1
4 3 2       5
```

Answer (score 1):

а в чем проблема то?

матрица `n x m` - это

```
float** matrix = new float*[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    matrix[i] = new float[m]
```

поэтому что матрица `1 x m`, что `n x 1` - это все равно двумерные массивы и работайте с ними как с двумерными массивами

просто к строке/столбцы вы будете обращаться как к `matrix2[0][i]` или `matrix2[i][0]` и не важно, что на экране вы ее выводите как строку или столбец - это и там и там таблица, просто вырожденная